# What is the difference between baking soda and baking powder?

Tags: substitutions, baking-soda, baking-powder

And can I use one in place of the other in certain recipes?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Normal double-acting baking powder makes CO2 (thus giving a rising effect) in two ways: when it gets wet, and when it is heated.

Baking soda only makes CO2 when it gets wet.

[From Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baking_powder):

> The acid in a baking powder can be
>   either fast-acting or slow-acting.[6]
>   A fast-acting acid reacts in a wet
>   mixture with baking soda at room
>   temperature, and a slow-acting acid
>   will not react until heated in an
>   oven. Baking powders that contain both
>   fast- and slow-acting acids are double
>   acting; those that contain only one
>   acid are single acting. By providing a
>   second rise in the oven, double-acting
>   baking powders increase the
>   reliability of baked goods by
>   rendering the time elapsed between
>   mixing and baking less critical, and
>   this is the type most widely available
>   to consumers today.

Comment: Note that it's the reaction to acidic ingredients that causes baking soda to produce CO2 which typically occurs during moistening of the dough/batter.  Just wanted to clarify so that people don't think that moisture alone will make baking soda react.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. Baking soda does not produce CO2 when it gets wet. (Try it!)

Answer (score 30):

Baking soda is pure sodium bicarbonate, while baking powder includes an acidifying agent (cream of tartar) and a drying agent (starch).

You can substitute baking soda for baking powder if you already have an acidifying agent in a recipe (like buttermilk).

http://chemistry.about.com/cs/foodchemistry/f/blbaking.htm

Comment: This answer is right. The 'accepted' answer seems more detailed, but those details are wrong. Thank you for mentioning the need for acid!

Answer (score 6):

You can make your own baking powder using baking soda, cornstarch, and cream of tartar.

1/4 tsp baking soda
1/2 tsp cream of tartar
1/4 tsp cornstarch

That will give you one tsp baking powder. Increase as necessary.

Also, if you don't have all those ingredients, you can use 3 measures of baking powder for every measure of baking soda, although you won't get the same flavor profile with the reduction of acidity from baking soda.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to forefinger's answer, I also believe baking powder has cream of tartar in it, making it more pH neutral.

Comment: Modern commercial baking powders don't typically include cream of tartar but rather different dry acids ( often monocalcium phosphate/sodium aluminum sulfate)  that react with moisture and heat which is what makes them "double-acting".  Pretty much all commercial baking powders are now double-acting.