# How do I make a "baking powder" substitute in a pinch?

Tags: baking, substitutions, baking-powder

Every once in while we run out of "Baking powder".

What would be a good recipe for a substitute that you have used that works well?

Comment: See also http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/4/what-is-the-difference-between-baking-soda-and-baking-powder/40#40

Comment: Also see also: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/46904/making-baking-powder-substitute-with-baking-soda-and-powdered-citric-acid

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On the off-chance that you have no baking powder, but you do have baking **soda** and cream of tartar, you can make your own baking powder:

- 1 teaspoon baking soda
- 2 teaspoons cream of tartar
- 1 teaspoon corn starch (optional)

Mix it all together and use it immediately.

Reference: http://frugalliving.about.com/od/condimentsandspices/r/Baking_Powder.htm

Answer (score 7):

It's important to note that homemade forms of baking powder need to be treated like recipes using only baking soda....they MUST go into the oven immediately otherwise the carbon dioxide bubbles will rise to the surface and pop, releasing the gas to the atmosphere instead of trapping it inside the baked goods.  The result will be a dense heavy texture.

Commercial baking powders allow muffins to be made the night before, scooped into a pan and then baked the next morning because the greater bulk of gas production occurs during the baking process when a heat-activated dry acid produces gas.

Comment: Thanks for the comments about home-made "Baking powder"!! I wonder if Julia Child ever wrote on this. One thing that I really like about Julia Child, is that she would test, test, test till the recipe really work.