# Substitution for baking soda in pancakes

Tags: baking, substitutions, pancakes, baking-soda

I attempted to make pancakes this morning, only to discover that I was out of baking soda. I tried substituting baking powder, but it didn't work at all. The pancakes didn't bubble on the griddle, and they were far too doughy. If this happens again, do I need to go out to the store for baking soda?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to [use 2-3 times more baking powder than baking soda](http://chemistry.about.com/od/foodchemistryfaqs/f/powdersoda.htm).  Be aware that your flavors will be affected. Make sure it's double-acting baking powder and you must replace the acidic liquid in recipe with non-acidic liquid.  You could also use some heartburn medicine that contained potassium bicarbonate :-)

Comment: +1 for the heartburn- as long as you don't mind the pancakes tasting like fruit. :)

Answer (score 10):

Unfortunately there is no substitute. While it is possible to substitute for [baking powder](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/530/how-do-i-make-a-baking-powder-substitute-in-a-pinch), the reverse just doesn't work the same. Tripling the quantity of baking powder to baking soda *will* give an equivalent reaction, but your pancakes will taste like metal.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend replacing the soda in the same recipe but there are plenty of pancake recipes that call for powder instead of soda.

Comment: @Sobachatina - powder is the secret ingredient in the recipe I use.

Comment: @Soba: I didn't say baking powder isn't used. Your comment seems to imply that I did. My pancakes use baking powder too. I was just referring to tripling the quantity of baking soda for a baking powder substitution.

Comment: I did misunderstand. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Using a [baking powder that does not contain aluminum compounds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baking_powder#Usage_of_Aluminum_compounds) might help alleviate that.

Answer (score 4):

You can use baking powder to leaven the batter but you can't replace baking soda with it 1 for 1.

Baking powder is soda with some acid to balance the ph. Pancake recipes that use only powder will not have extra acid, such as buttermilk, added to them.

I love buttermilk. If I were making the pancakes I would go buy soda rather than having an under-flavored breakfast. Baking soda keeps indefinitely and is useful for a lot of things. Buy enough that you never run out again.

Answer (score 2):

When no baking powder is handy, you can make [pancakes using yeast](http://www.food.com/recipe/yeast-pancakes-347002)*.

It takes longer, having to let the yeast rise for 30 minutes and all, but I've done it, and the result is really *really* tasty pancakes!

---

*No endorsement of this recipe is implied, it's merely the first one I ran across.

Answer (score 0):

Use 2 times the amount of baking powder and a higher temp.
As for acid I'm not sure. I sub it in cake recipes (and never cared about the acid). In fact I use extra lemon juice for softness and it never interfered.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to make pancakes with non of both.

In Germany I have yet to meet someone who adds it. I guess the pancakes are thinner but they are tasty non the less.

Or you can carefully add whipped egg-white to the batter just before baking. That's how the very fluffy [Kaiserschmarrn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaiserschmarrn) is made. The air contained in the stiff egg-white does more or less the same as the CO2 produced by Soda or baking powder.

For yet another option add some sparkling water to the batter.

Answer (score -1):

Someone posted this on a different site. I am going to try it.

The only trouble I had was remembering the amounts. So, I wrote the following down and taped it to the inside of my baking cabinet.

to equal the leavening of:

- 1 teaspoon baking powder . . .  use 1/4 teaspoon baking soda *plus* 1 teaspoon vinegar
- 2 teaspoons baking powder . . . use 1/2 teaspoon baking soda *plus* 2 teaspoons vinegar
- 1 tablespoon baking powder. . . use 3/4 teaspoon baking soda *plus* 1 tablespoon vinegar

Comment: The question is about replacing baking soda with baking powder, not the reverse.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, there is a substitution. It is a combination of cream of tartar and salt!

Comment: I responded to your post in error.