# Baking powder substitutes

Tags: baking, substitutions, pizza, baking-soda

So I found this amazing pizza dough recipe. It calls for flour and baking powder (or self rising flour) and sour cream, but I do not have self rising flour or baking powder/soda.

Is there anything I can do to make this work? And basic recipes to use instead? Or even any other pizza dough recipe that doesn't call for this?

Comment: Aside from the fact that - as Patrick Hofman already stated - you usually use yeast: [How do I make a “baking powder” substitute in a pinch](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/530/23376)

Comment: If you don't have baking powder, you're even less likely to have yeast... Is popping round to the store to buy it out of the question?

Comment: I suppose we could guess that you have flour, and might be able to develop a sourdough culture from it in a few weeks. But going to the store seems like a more practical approach, unless you are stuck on an island with flour, internet and a pizza oven, but no store or boat to get to one.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with your specific recipe, but I usually use yeast in bread or pizza dough.

You can use dried and fresh yeast, either works for me. You need to let it rise for an hour or so when you prepared the dough. You could put it all mixed together in a bowl and put that in warm water. That will speed up the rising process.